# How to convert propositional formula to DNF in Coq

Tags: normalization, coq

I have defined my propositional formulas as follows:

```
Inductive propForm : Set :=
| top : propForm
| bot : propForm
| var : propVar -> propForm
| orp : propForm -> propForm -> propForm
| andp : propForm -> propForm -> propForm.
```

I am trying to define a function for transforming a propositional formula into one in DNF. For this, I have defined a function which distributes terms using the distributive law:

```
Fixpoint distribute (f:propForm) : propForm -> propForm :=
fix distribute1 (g:propForm) : propForm :=
match f with
| f1 \/p f2 => match g with
            | g1 \/p g2 => distribute1 g1 \/p distribute1 g2
            | _ => distribute f1 g \/p distribute f2 g
            end
| _ => match g with
       | g1 \/p g2 => distribute1 g1 \/p distribute1 g2
       | _ => f /\p g
       end
end.
```

This function works fine. However, I still need to define a function which transforms the propositional formula to DNF. The following function would do what I want, however it is not accepted by Coq because the function is not structurally decreasing in f' for the last case. Any hints and tips would be appreciated.

```
Fixpoint toDNF (f':propForm):propForm :=
match f' with
| top => f'
| bot => f'
| var _ => f'
| f1 \/p f2 => toDNF f1 \/p toDNF f2
| f1 /\p f2 => toDNF (distribute f1 f2)
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is a special case of normalizing an expression from a semi-ring. I wrote a [post](http://poleiro.info/posts/2015-04-13-writing-reflective-tactics.html) explaining how to do that in the case of arithmetic expressions, using the Ssreflect and MathComp libraries, but I'll include a more direct answer here.

One idea is to use lists of lists to represent formulas in DNF: after all, they are just a conjunction of a list of disjunctions, which are just lists of literals. You can then reuse the list library to write your function:

```
Module Sol1.

Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Notation propVar := nat.

Inductive propAtom :=
| top | bot | var :> propVar -> propAtom.

Inductive propForm : Set :=
| atom :> propAtom -> propForm
| orp : propForm -> propForm -> propForm
| andp : propForm -> propForm -> propForm.

Definition dnfForm := list (list propAtom).

Fixpoint andd (f1 f2 : dnfForm) : dnfForm :=
  match f1 with
  | [] =>
    (* false && f2 = false *)
    []
  | cf :: f1 =>
    (* (cf || f1) && f2 = cf && f2 || f1 && f2 *)
    map (app cf) f2 ++ andd f1 f2
  end.

Fixpoint toDNF (f : propForm) : dnfForm :=
  match f with
  | atom a => [[a]]
  | orp f1 f2 => toDNF f1 ++ toDNF f2
  | andp f1 f2 => andd (toDNF f1) (toDNF f2)
  end.

Compute (toDNF (andp (orp 3 4) (orp 1 2))).

End Sol1.
```

There are two things to note here. First, I factored variables and constants as a separate `propAtom` type, and I have called `distribute` `andd`, because you can think of it as computing the AND of two expressions in DNF.

Here's another solution that is based on your original code. It seems that your `distribute` function preserves the invariant of being in DNF; that is, if `f1` and `f2` are in DNF, then so is `distribute f1 f2`. Thus, you can just flip the order of the calls:

```
Module Sol2.

Notation propVar := nat.

Inductive propForm : Set :=
| top : propForm
| bot : propForm
| var :> propVar -> propForm
| orp : propForm -> propForm -> propForm
| andp : propForm -> propForm -> propForm.

Fixpoint distribute (f:propForm) : propForm -> propForm :=
fix distribute1 (g:propForm) : propForm :=
match f with
| orp f1 f2 => match g with
            | orp g1 g2 => orp (distribute1 g1) (distribute1 g2)
            | _ => orp (distribute f1 g) (distribute f2 g)
            end
| _ => match g with
       | orp g1 g2 => orp (distribute1 g1) (distribute1 g2)
       | _ => andp f g
       end
end.

Fixpoint toDNF (f':propForm):propForm :=
match f' with
| top => f'
| bot => f'
| var _ => f'
| orp f1 f2 => orp (toDNF f1) (toDNF f2)
| andp f1 f2 => distribute (toDNF f1) (toDNF f2)
end.

Compute (toDNF (andp (orp 3 4) (orp 1 2))).

End Sol2.
```

Comment: Thank you, I had actually all ready proven that my distribute indeed preserves the invariant of being in DNF. However, I had not realized the repercussion that I could flip the order of the calls. Because I need equivalence between the propositional formulas, defining a sepperate type would have been a lot of work, since I would also require complete and sound conversions.

Comment: I see your point, but it's not actually too bad, since you can always write a function to convert a DNF formula (as a list of lists) back to a generic one. If you have a good infrastructure to reason about lists and algebraic structures (as Ssreflect provides), then the amount of code that you'll save definitely justifies using this approach.